# should we backup & reload data when upgrade to higher version of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Recently, I have updated from MongoDB 1.6 to MongoDB 2.0.

I have populated several collections on MongoDB 1.6. After I upgrade to MongoDB 2.0, then start mongodb with the same --dbpath parameter, I found that all previous store collections are still there.

It seems that I don't have to manually backup and reload data into the newer version.

Question> When should we backup & reload data if we decide to upgrade to new version mongodb?

Thank you

Comment: YOU SHOULD ALWAYS BACKUP YOUR DATA BEFORE PATCHING. (end of community service message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always backup your data before changing versions - doesn't matter up or down. I'd recommend using `mongodump` which is super fast (I can tell from my experience, we were able to dump about 15M documents, 12GB database in 2 minutes). Once you've done this, upgrade the binaries and see if the existing data works. If not, restore from the dump using `mongorestore`.

Comment: One note after update to 2.0, in case if you will need downgrade version back you need to recreate indexes, because of mongodb 2.0 has new indexes version.

Answer (score 0):

It#s clearly documented that the database format did not change. So swapping the binaries should be good enough.